# remove element from vector on their size

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
a = c("sdfdfdf","dfdfd","dfdf","dfdfdfd","dfdf")
```

I want to keep only those elements, which have size >5. How can I do that

Output should be

```
a = c("sdfdfdf","dfdfdfd")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `nchar`

```
a[nchar(a)>5]
```

`nchar` counts the number of characters per string see `?nchar`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `str_length` from `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
a[str_length(a) > 5]
#[1] "sdfdfdf" "dfdfdfd"
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but my guess is that it's needlessly complicated to use a library when there is a base-R function that literally does the same.

Comment: @Heroka completely agreed. But can't we even give an alternative? Do we have to strictly follow one and only one solution?

Comment: Again, I didn't downvote. I think that working (and non-working, for that matter) answers shouldn't be downvoted without a reason. But it happens, people can be ****.

Comment: not me either, but see `z <- sample(a, 10000, replace = TRUE); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(z[str_length(z) > 5], z[nchar(z)>5])`, it is more efficient

Comment: @jeremycg Based on the benchmark `stringr` function is efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Another method with grepl:

```
a[grepl('\\w{6,}',a)]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
library(stringr)
a[str_detect(a, '^.{6,}$')]
#[1] "sdfdfdf" "dfdfdfd"
```